# Different vertical alignments of Bootstrap columns, without fixed height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, bootstrap-5

I am trying to reproduce this configuration, where 3 columns have 3 different vertical alignments:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#vertical-alignment

This is what I get:

[Codepen 1](https://codepen.io/pbonneau/pen/OJzaEJp)

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col red align-self-start">Align Start</div>
    <div class="col yellow align-self-center">Align Center</div>
    <div class="col green align-self-end">Align End</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

I am aware that if I define the row's height it would work:

[Codepen 2](https://codepen.io/pbonneau/pen/XWVyYgL)

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex min-vh-100">
    <div class="col red align-self-start">Align Start</div>
    <div class="col yellow align-self-center">Align Center</div>
    <div class="col green align-self-end">Align End</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**How could I do so the row's height is the sum of the 3 columns content ?** (It would vary depending on the content)

Comment: Why don't you put all these three div in different rows and just use justify-content to align them horizontally? You would get the intended result

Comment: I could get something similar yes, but wouldn't I loose the constraint columns put on each others width ?